# Error: Character argument 'a' at (1) must be length 1 because procedure is BIND(C)

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

```
subroutine func01( a ) bind(C,name="func01")
  implicit none
  character(len=30), dimension(3) , intent(in) :: a

    print *
    print *, "char length = ", len(a(1)), len(a(2)), len(a(3))
    print *, "raw a(1) : [", a(1), "]"
    print *, "raw a(2) : [", a(2), "]"
    print *, "raw a(3) : [", a(3), "]"
    print *, "trim     : [", trim(a(1)), "] [", trim(a(2)), "]  [", trim(a(3)), "]"
end
```

When I try to compile the above code I get the following messages:

```
gfortran source3.f90

source3.f90:1.20:

subroutine func01( a ) bind(C,name="func01")
                    1
Warning: Variable 'a' at (1) is a parameter to the BIND(C) procedure 'func01' bu
t may not be C interoperable
source3.f90:1.20:

subroutine func01( a ) bind(C,name="func01")
                    1
Error: Character argument 'a' at (1) must be length 1 because procedure 'func01'
 is BIND(C)
```

Can you please tell me on how to get rid of the messages?

Comment: As you can see in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/fortran-iso-c-binding/info `a` isn't an interoperable thing (it isn't of length 1)..  You will be able to find many other questions about passing a string from C to Fortran.

Comment: It compiles just fine with ifort intel compiler

Comment: Yeah, Intel allows that, but that is their non-standard choice.

Comment: How do I fix it to run with gfortran

Comment: You will have to restructure it to use character(1) arrays. We cannot say more, because we cannot see the rest of the code, but it will have to be restructured, not just one line changed.

Comment: See for example http://stackoverflow.com/q/8207997/577108, and maybe http://stackoverflow.com/q/9972743/577108

Comment: can you add at least the declared C interface `func01` to this post and how you are calling that function in C?

Comment: extern "C" {
    void func01( char *c, const int len );
}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419704/fortran-pass-character81-array-to-c-c-code

Comment: subroutine func01( a ) bind(C,name="func01")
  implicit none
  character(len=1), dimension(90) , intent(in) :: a
  character(len=30), dimension(3) :: b
  integer*4 :: count,i,j

    count=1
    do j=1,3
    b(J)=''
    do I=1,30
    b(J)=trim(b(J))//a(count)
    count=count+1
    enddo
    enddo

    print *
    print *, "char length = ", len(b(1)), len(b(2)), len(b(3))
    print *, "raw a(1) : [", b(1), "]"
    print *, "raw a(2) : [", b(2), "]"
    print *, "raw a(3) : [", b(3), "]"
    print *, "trim     : [", trim(b(1)), "] [", trim(b(2)), "]  [", trim(b(3)), "]"
end

Comment: @bjdesa What? If you have some new code edit it into the question and format it properly. This is absolutely unreadable.

Answer (score 4):

A character argument of a Fortran `bind(C)` interoperable procedure must have length 1.

But one can use the same approach as in C, use the arrays of characters.

If you have

```
char ch[5]
```

use

```
character(kind=c_char) :: ch(5)
```

If you have

```
char* ch;
int n;

ch = malloc(n);
fortran_sub(ch, n);
```

use

```
subroutine fortran_sub(ch, n) bind(C, name="fortran_sub")
  integer(c_int), value :: n
  character(kind = c_char) :: ch(n)
```

Note that the character array will be null delimited.

If you are calling C and passing the character array there, it is your responsibility to delimit it by `c_char_null`.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but how do you do then a clean interoperation between C and Fortran. It seems you need to first convert all your arrays `ch(n)` to `character(len=n) :: new_ch` before you can work it properly in Fortran.

Comment: @kvantour See notes 18.17 and 18.21 in Fortran 2015 draft (in final F2018 the numbers may differ). *"Fortran’s rules of sequence association (15.5.2.11) permit a character scalar actual argument to correspond
to a dummy argument array. This makes it possible to argument associate a Fortran character string with
a C string.
Note 18.21 has an example of interoperation between Fortran and C strings."*