# The correct way to pass a string from Fortran to C/C++

Tags: c++, string, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I want to pass a string from Fortran to C/C++. Here is my Fortran code:

```
subroutine zdplaskinGetSpeciesName(cstring, index) bind(C, name='zdplaskinGetSpeciesName')
  use iso_c_binding
  use ZDPlasKin
  implicit none
  integer, intent(in) :: index
  CHARACTER(10), TARGET :: fstring = ''
  TYPE(C_PTR) :: cstring
  fstring = species_name(index+1)
  cstring = c_loc(fstring)
end subroutine zdplaskinGetSpeciesName
```

`ZDPlasKin` is a module which has `species_name(i)`.

```
extern "C" void zdplaskinGetSpeciesName(char* cstring[], size_t* index);
char* cstring[1];
size_t index = 1;
zdplaskinGetSpeciesName(cstring, &index);
string speciesName = string(cstring[0]);
cout << speciesName << endl;
```

The output seems to be fine for this method. However, I want to trim the trailing space (`character(10`) gives extra space), so my C++ code can read the string correctly. I tried another way.

```
subroutine zdplaskinGetSpeciesName(cstring, index) bind(C, name='zdplaskinGetSpeciesName')
  use iso_c_binding
  use ZDPlasKin
  implicit none
  integer, intent(in) :: index
  CHARACTER(:), allocatable, TARGET :: fstring
  TYPE(C_PTR) :: cstring
  fstring = trim(species_name(index+1))
  cstring = c_loc(fstring)
end subroutine zdplaskinGetSpeciesName
```

But this way I got some weird symbols.

---

I want to do things correctly so I don't need to worry later. Memory leak is not what I want. So I think I will try the alternative way you suggested. I think I would like to know is how can I know if I need to deallocate a pointer. Here is another code I found on StackOverflow (Although this one passes C++ string to Fortran. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30430656/721644)

Do you think this is okay to use? Or there might be memory leak. Also can you give me some hint about the alternative way you suggested?

Comment: *But this way I got some weird symbols.* What did you get?

Comment: Note there is no language C/C++ and some people here who do C and C++ are VERY allergic to that. Fortranners usually don't care. I understand it is calling in C++ through the C interoperability so I am not opposed to both tags, but many other people are.

Comment: Both versions can never work. The local allocatable string will be deallocated when the subroutine exits.  The local variable is only valid on the stack during the execution.

Comment: The code you link is likely correct, but it does something else. As I said, there is a lot you useful you can  find on StackOverflow, but you should probably not bring each of it here.

Answer (score 5):

Variants of this were treated in many other questions. Searching for an exact duplicate for closure is probably hopeless, but I **strongly** suggest you to search and read those questions and answers.

C strings are null-terminated. If you want to trim it, you just put the null character to the right place. Actually, you are not null terminating the string in your first version at all so it is prone to buffer overflow.

But even worse, the variable `fstring` is only local to the function. NEVER pass pointers to local variables.

So, the first version should really be

```
subroutine zdplaskinGetSpeciesName(cstring, index) bind(C, name='zdplaskinGetSpeciesName')
  use iso_c_binding
  use ZDPlasKin
  implicit none
  integer, intent(in) :: index
  CHARACTER(11), POINTER :: fstring
  TYPE(C_PTR) :: cstring
  allocate(fstring)
  fstring = species_name(index+1)
  fstring(11:11) = c_null_char
  cstring = c_loc(fstring)
end subroutine zdplaskinGetSpeciesName
```

To trim the string you just place the null char to the right place

```
   integer :: len
   ...
   len = len_trim(fstring)
   fstring(len+1:len+1) = c_null_char
```

You can also use a pointer to a character array of length that will match the length of the string + 1 or a deferred length (`character(:)`) character pointer similar to your second approach. Just remember to always leave 1 character for the null termination.

Now the code will have a memory leak. To get away of the memory leak, the string MUST be deallocated from Fortran! So you must create a special subroutine to deallocate these pointers.

---

An alternative is to pass a pointer to a buffer from C++ and just fill the string in Fortran. I would actually prefer that way. You can make it null-terminated already in C++, just be sure to not let Fortran to overwrite the terminating character.

You can try:

```
subroutine zdplaskinGetSpeciesName(cstring, index) bind(C, name='zdplaskinGetSpeciesName')
  use iso_c_binding
  use ZDPlasKin
  implicit none
  integer, intent(in) :: index
  TYPE(C_PTR), intent(in) :: cstring
  CHARACTER(kind=C_CHAR), POINTER :: fstring(:)
  integer :: i, c_len, name_len

  c_len = c_strlen(cstring)
  c_f_pointer(cstring, fstring, [c_len])

  associate(name => species_name(index+1))
    name_len = trim_len(name)
    do i = 1, name_len
      fstring(i) = name(i:i)
    end do
    fstring(name_len+1:name_len+1)
  end do
end subroutine zdplaskinGetSpeciesName
```

Untested. You are responsible to provide large enough null-terminated buffer from C++. `c_strlen` can be found at http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/c_interface_module

---

To be 100% standard conforming you should use arrays of characters `character(kind=c_char)` of length one, but strings are very likely to work in practice.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I want to do things correctly so I don't need to worry later. Memory leak is not what I want. So I think I will try the alternative way you suggested. I think I would like to know is how can I know if I need to deallocate a pointer. Here is another code I found on stackoverflow:

Comment: You do not need to paste here the code from other SO question, a link is enough. But what do you want to do with that code? It does something different.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got a good way. First, download http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/c_interface_module. And use F_C_string_ptr.

```
subroutine zdplaskinGetSpeciesName(cstring, index) bind(C, name='zdplaskinGetSpeciesName')
  use ZDPlasKin
  use C_interface_module
  implicit none
  integer, intent(in) :: index
  TYPE(C_PTR), intent(in) :: cstring
  character(:), allocatable :: fstring
  fstring = trim(species_name(index+1))
  call F_C_string_ptr(fstring, cstring)
end subroutine zdplaskinGetSpeciesName
```

And c and c++ code are:

```
extern "C" void zdplaskinGetSpeciesName(char* cstring[], size_t* index);
for (size_t i = 0; i < zdplaskinNSpecies(); i++) {
    char* cstring[10];
    zdplaskinGetSpeciesName(cstring, &i);
    printf("%s\n",*cstring);
    string speciesName(*cstring);
    cout << speciesName << endl;
}
```

Comment: The allocation to fstring is completely unnecessary. You can remove the `fstring` variable altogether. `call F_C_string_ptr(trim(species_name(index+1)), cstring)` Also, your `cstring[10]` is likely too short and expect buffer overflows.

Comment: *"If the length is not passed, the C string must be at least: `len(F_string)+1`".*